# Auto-leveling bug with mothership modes in arras.io

Tags: arras.io

Sometimes when I enter a Mothership arena in [arras.io](https://arras.io), even with `Auto Level-Up` enabled and constantly pressing the key `n`, I still do not level up. This is only the case sometimes, so I presume this is a bug. Is this really a bug or intended, and should this be fixed?